# collection-type argument in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I was thinking if I could set the list elements type in hibernate mapping files.

So far I found this collection-type attribute like here:

`<list name="privileges" cascade="all" table="user_privilege" collection-type="">`

, but I am not sure if I put my list element full class name if Hibernate will generate my domain classes properly.

Is there another way of doing this or I have to manually set types of my Lists in my classes like here:

Generated by Hibernate:

```
private List privileges = new ArrayList(0);
```

Manually changed:

```
private List<UserPrivilege> privileges = new ArrayList(0);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`collection-type` attribute set's type of collection class if you want to use some custom Collection implementation, other then standard `java.util.ArrayList` et consortes.

If your mappings are correct it's just a matter of hbm2java tool settings. See [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e5215).

Example:

```
<hibernatetool destdir="${build.dir}/generated">
  <configuration configurationfile="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
  <hbm2java jdk5="true"/>
</hibernatetool>
```